# Count how many rows have at least one certain value

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I'm using Oracle SQL and i need a help with a query.

I need to count how many rows have at least one value of `NA`.

My table have more than 300 columns (these are not the real columns names):

```
col1 varchar,
col2 varchar,
col3 varchar,
...
...
...
col300 varchar
```

Here is an example of a table:

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4
 10  | 15   | 55   |  NA
 NA  | 15   | 55   |  NA
 10  | 15   | 55   |  33
 10  | NA   | 55   |  58
 10  | 15   | 55   |  33
 10  | 15   | 55   |  84
 10  | 15   | NA   |  40

Output expected result: 4
```

Please advise.

Comment: I advice to change your table design. Having 300 columns is a bad design for sure.

Comment: I can't change it. That's how i got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've found the solution.

```
select sum(cnt) from
(
select case when 
       col1 = 'NA'
    or col2 = 'NA'
    or col3 = 'NA'
    or col4 = 'NA' then 1 end cnt
from MyTable  
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a Sum of a sub select using a case to get this:

```
Select SUM(NA)

From

(Select case when col1 = 'NA' then 1 case when col2 = 'NA' then 1 case when col3 = 'NA' then 1 case when col4 = 'NA' then 1 end as NA
from Table) a
```

Comment: Your subquery is not correct but it's gave my a good idea for a solution. I've just posted it.

Answer (score 0):

Use count

```
SELECT
  COUNT(1)
FROM
  table_name
WHERE
  'NA' IN (col1, col2, ..., col300)
```